# How do I uninstall Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall, windows-xp

I installed Lubuntu using a USB drive. It is dual boot. I want to get back to just Windows XP. I don't have the disk for XP though. Is there any way to do this? Please keep in mind that I'm almost entirely new to Lubuntu and don't know much about it. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a WUBI install inside of MS Windows or a normal install?  There is a difference when you want to uninstall.

Comment: It's a normal install. I didn't use Wubi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reinstate the Windows boot loader to the MBR so that only Windows boots. You can then use disk manager to delete the Ubuntu partitions.  This question has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on).

It is organized step by step so you can choose the answer that applies to you.